PHP hex2bin limitation
I am converting data like html, css from browser textarea to hex to post it via ajax to the server. This is to avoid triggering modsecurity xss firewall rules.
In the server I am using PHP's hex2bin to convert the hex back to html.
Everything is working as it should BUT it is not converting some characters like £ whose hex is a3, PHP's hex2bin renders it as � in the browser.
There are many other such hex codes hex2bin doesn't convert. Am I doing something wrong or is there some other library that I can use to get full hex coverage?
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

//javascript
var str = '£';
var hex = str.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
alert(hex); // a3

//php
echo hex2bin('a3'); // �
echo hex2bin('24'); // $
echo hex2bin('ae'); // � should be ®


Sounds like you're not displaying with the correct charset.

Are you using ASCII in js and UTF8 in PHP? c2a3 should be utf8. Can you please add more context to the question.

see my question, I have added the js & php code that I am using

Are you doing this just as some sort of exercise, or is this supposed to serve any actual purpose? (Just trying to figure out if you might be trying to re-invent any wheels here.)

hex2bin() works perfectly fine. You are just not producing a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.

i am converting html, css & javascript from browser textarea to hex to post it via ajax to the server to save it in a database. This is to avoid triggering modsecurity xss firewall rules.

A solution is to use the utf8ToHex() function given here. utf8ToHex('£') returns c2a3, which will give the expected result when decoded by hex2bin().

For reference, £ is U+00A3 'POUND SIGN'. a3 is the Unicode code point, which is basically a catalogue number and it's different from the actual encoding being used.

String.prototype.charCodeAt() produces:

an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.

Since your HTML document is declaring UTF-8, you need to convert between encodings. But you're also missing information when the first byte is zero, so you need to pad the value first:
$utf16 = hex2bin(str_pad('a3', 4,  '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
echo mb_convert_encoding($utf16, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');

Doing this one character at a time is not going to perform nicely. If you really need serialisation at all (i.e. you cannot use raw UTF-8 for whatever the reason), I'd suggest you use some other serialisation mechanism such as Base64:


function bytesToBase64(bytes) {
  const binString = Array.from(bytes, (byte) =>
    String.fromCodePoint(byte),
  ).join("");
  return btoa(binString);
}

const message = 'We accept £ and €';
console.log(bytesToBase64(new TextEncoder().encode(message)));



(Code taken from MDN).
echo base64_decode('V2UgYWNjZXB0IMKjIGFuZCDigqw=');


mb_convert_encoding the padded hex2bin solves the issue in this question. However, bytesToBase64 method as proposed by Álvaro is a better solution for the application I am working on. thank you for the answer.

I have posted a function derived from this answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78723233/post-raw-html-data-via-ajax-to-server-with-modsecurity/
